# Unable to load project environment variable in Spring Boot Unit Test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit

I have some variables defined in application-local.yml in my spring boot project and these variables are used in many of the services by using @Value annotation.
Now while trying to unit test these services, the service is unable to retrieve the value of the variable from the application-local.yml and instead is throwing NullPointer Exception.
What should I do?

application-local.yml :

```
variables:
    maxVal: 24
```

Service.java

```
@Value("${variables.maxVal:24}")
public Integer maxima;

FunctionA()
{
  return maxima+1;
}
```

Unit Test

```
@Test
testFunctionA()
{
  assert.assertEquals(25,FunctionA())
}
```

Comment: Can u share your test , Your probably missing annotation for the test class .

Comment: @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class testFunctionA {}

Answer (score 0):

your properties file is not being loaded. the proper manner for test properties is to use a application-test.yaml, located under test/resources, it will be automatically loaded when you run your tests.

Answer (score 0):

You can injecting the property in the context with Spring Boot in this simple way thanks to the properties attribute of @SpringBootTest :

```
@SpringBootTest(properties="property.value=dummyValue")
public class FooTest{
    
   @Autowired
   Foo foo;
     
   @Test
   public void doThat(){
       ...
   }    
}
```

You could use as alternative @TestPropertySource but it adds an additional annotation :

```
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(properties="property.value=dummyValue")
public class FooTest{ ...}
```

With Spring (without Spring Boot), it should be a little more complicated but as I didn't use Spring without Spring Boot from a long time I don't prefer say a stupid thing.

As a side note : if you have many @Value fields to set, extracting them into a class annotated with @ConfigurationProperties is more relevant because we don't want a constructor with too many arguments.

Hope thats helped .